# Visual Studio method/variable menu keeps disappearing (Also not sure what terminology I should use to find related answers)

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to demonstrate the problem I am having via this video on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RcDn1UQtbcWwILkaDaf5MgI-5PL6NS0-/view?usp=sharing

Part 1 of the video) I do not do anything with the method menu for a moment so I may attempt to read its information. Something happens that causes it to close.

Part 2 of the video) I try to see if I can use my mouse to try and select from the method menu. However, something also happens that causes the method menu to close.

Part 3 of the video) I am trying to quickly use the down arrow key to browse through the options, but some process seems to happen as my cursor turns into a loading circle, causing me to actually go down lines of code using the down arrow key.

I have never encountered this before, and I am not sure what is causing this. There were a few times earlier today when I could use the down arrow key and leave the method menu on for a bit to read more information and things seemed fine for a moment, and then there are other times like these when the method menu is disappearing on me. I'm not sure how to search this up because I'm not really sure what appropriate terminology I should use when trying to see who else has had this problem.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.9.4 with the .NET Framework version of 4.8.04084